# Google Cloud Batch - Error: Message: Required 'compute.subnetworks.get' permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

Scenario - Running Google Cloud Batch jobs on project A using a shared VPC to use the region and subnetwork of host project B

On the service account, I have following permission on both project A and B

```
Compute Network User
```

But still I get this error

```
Job gets non-retryable information Batch Error: code - CODE_GCE_PERMISSION_DENIED, description - googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.subnetworks.get' permission for
```

What am I missing here? or what other permission should this have? Thanks for looking into this.

I have searched Google's official documentation, but there is no mention of this issue. I have found related issues in the dataFlow documentation, but I have added the corresponding permissions to the service account of Google cloud Batch

Answer (score 1):

I have figured the issue, There are three things to keep in mind here

1. The service account which is used to submit a batch jobtool needs to have below permission on both project and host project

   Compute Network User
2. Then we have two other service accounts that need permissions, service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-cloudbatch.iam.gserviceaccount.com AND PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com  Service account needs permission for on host project B with Compute Network User
3. Need to bind the subnet of Share VPC in PROJECT A

Answer (score 0):

The error message you mentioned googleapi: Error 403: Required compute.subnetworks.get permission indicates that the service account being used to run the Google Cloud Batch jobs does not have the necessary permission to access the subnetwork in the host project. This can be resolved by granting the service account the roles/compute.networkUser role on the subnetwork in the host project using a google_compute_subnetwork_iam_binding resource. This will allow the service account to use the shared subnetwork.